# O que é MurmurHash?

Tags: hash

Eu vi que está sendo programado para próxima versão do PHP 8.1 a implementação do [MurmurHash](https://php.watch/versions/8.1).

Eu nunca tinha ouvido falar sobre. Gostaria de saber do que se trata.

Comment: É um hash não criptográfico (não serve para segurança, pode servir para integridade), mas que de sacanagem nesse link seu foi comparado com criptográficos (justo seria ter o CRC32 na lista, que eu desconfio que ele perca, ou no máximo empate). Assim como o CRC32, ele é incremental (stream), ou seja, você pode ir calculando ele sem precisar por inteiro na memória, usa o valor anterior e "incrementa". Edit: confirmado num link mais extenso, ele perde pro CRC32: https://php.watch/articles/php-hash-benchmark - o que tem de interessante em algumas das variações é que tem mais bits que o CRC32

Comment: Briga de cachorro grande.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> MurmurHash (família de algoritmo de hash Murmur) é um hash não criptográfico com foco em altas performance, otimização e resistência a colisões.

## Introdução

Para entender a motivação por trás do MurmurHash (um hash não criptográfico), é preciso entender, primeiramente, alguns dos principais fatores necessários para que um algoritmo hash seja considerado **[critptográfico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_hash_criptogr%C3%A1fica)**:

- Resistência a [colisões](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack);
- Resistente ao [ataque *pre-image*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack);
- Bom [efeito avalanche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect) (isso significa, em resumo, que mudar uma ínfima parte da entrada representa enorme alteração na saída).
- Determinístico (uma mesma entrada deve *sempre* produzir mesma saída).
- Ser unidirecional (de modo a tornar impossível obter a mensagem original a partir do hash).

Uma vez que algum desses requisitos não tenha sido propriamente cumprido, o algoritmo deixa de ser considerado *função hash criptográfica*, passando a ser chamado de *função hash **não** criptográfica*.

Não pense que uma função hash não criptográfica perde a sua utilidade por não servir para fins criptográficos. Embora alguns algoritmos como MD5 ou SHA1 tenham sido rebaixados de hashes criptográficos para a classificação de *não* criptográficos (em detrimento de suas respectivas obsolescências), alguns hashes são desenvolvidos como não criptográficos desde o início para desempenhar algumas tarefas com desempenho superior. É o caso do MurmurHash.

[image: Trade offs: Trade offs everywhere]

## MurmurHash

O nome veio das duas operações básicas utilizadas em sua implementação, **mu**ltiplicação (MU) e **r**otação (R). Do inglês, ***mu**ltiply* e ***r**otate*.

Em resumo, algoritmos da família Murmur abrem mão de parte da "segurança criptográfica" para aumentar a eficiência e performance. Desse modo, MurmurHash:

- É simples em termos da quantidade de instruções Assembly geradas;
- Bom [efeito avalanche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect);
- Boa resistência a colisões (para chaves de até 4 bits colisões são garantidamente impossíveis);
- Otimizado para arquitetura Intel/AMD, de modo que representa um bom *tradeoff* entre qualidade de hash e consumo de CPU.

Observe então que o MurmurHash abre mão de certa parte da segurança (especificamente na resistência contra reversibilidade) para ganhos em performance e otimização.

Embora não seja, por isso, ideal para fins criptográficos, pode ser uma boa opção para implementações de certos tipos de [*hash tables*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), uma vez que é rápido e relativamente resistente a colisões.

Além disso, MurmurHash é um *streaming hash*, o que significa que os valores podem ser atualizados em sequência sem a necessidade de recomputar utilizando a string inteira. Ou seja, pode ser utilizado de modo incremental, algo extremamente útil em *strems* de dados.

[Um outro exemplo de uso interessante aqui.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11899616/7445826)

#### Referência

Recursos e fontes que utilizei para elaborar esta resposta.

- [`murmurhash`](https://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/)
- [MurmurHash - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash)
- [MurmurHash - What is it? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11899616/7445826)

Answer (score -5):

É um algorítmo não criptográfico criado por Austin Appleby.

Foi criado para ter alta performance no uso de buscas e identificações de conteúdo mas não para criptografia de segurança

Tem libs para várias linguagens como python e NodeJS

Dá uma olhada no repositório
https://github.com/ksss/digest-murmurhash

Comment: Isso qualquer um pode dizer. O mesmo já foi colocado bem claro nos comentários para evitar que alguém responda com trivialidade. O outro comentário foi bem explicito "Briga de cachorro grande" a respostas competindo por votos e recompensas deve ter conteúdo técnico.  O autor quer saber formalmente, como o algoritmo funciona.

Comment: Ok, sem problema, mas sua pergunta foi "Eu nunca tinha ouvido falar sobre. Gostaria de saber do que se trata." Acredito que eu respondi o que se trata. Se quer saber mais sobre como é o algorimo, só olhar o código no link que botei ali! Valeu. Abraço.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no perfil do autor da pergunta. Ele escreve algoritmos criptográficos com as mão amarradas.